# Automation testing error while starting Test Cases

Tags: android, automation, pycharm, appium

What is causing this error when I run my Android app's automated testing?

```
 C:\Users\sujan\PycharmProjects\code\auto_env\OTT_Client
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "src/Utilities_test/Convert_csvToPy.py", line 13, in <module>
    from template.cases_template import test_case_dict
ImportError: bad magic number in 'template': b'\x03\xf3\r\n'
command 'python src/Utilities_test/Convert_csvToPy.py Test_cases.csv' return with error (code 1): b''
```

Answer (score 1):

This error probably is a result of a mix between 2.7 & 3+ versions, also happens if you have manually named your file with an extension .pyc

Answer (score 1):

the error isn't actually coming from your test cases. The magic number comes from UNIX-type systems where the first few bytes of a file held a marker indicating the file type. Python puts a similar marker into its pyc files when it creates them.
Then the python interpreter makes sure this number is correct when loading it.

Anything that corrupts this magic number will cause your problem, like if you edit a pyc file or your trying to run from a different version of python

as for fixing it you could try a few things. You could try to do a clean on the pyc files something like

```
find . -name "*.pyc" -exec rm -f {} \;
```

The command above will delete all pyc files recursively. then just run again and it should recompile

or if you cloned something from a repo just delete and and reclone